# Suppose $G$ has a lower central series and $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Show an index $k$ such that $G^{k+1} \subset H$ but $G^k \not\subset H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

> Suppose $G$ has a lower central series and $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Show that there is an index $k$ such that $G^{k+1} \subset H$ but $G^k \not\subset H$.

If $G$ has a lower central series then,
$$G=G^{0} \triangleright G^{1} \triangleright \cdots \triangleright G^{n}=\{e\}$$
is a subnormal series where $G^i=[G^{i-1},G]=\langle [x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \mid x \in G^{i-1}, y \in G \rangle$

I'm not sure as to why should the claim be true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G^n=\{e\}\subset H$.  And $G^0=G\not\subset H$, since $H$ is a proper subgroup. So let $k=\operatorname{min}\{j\mid G^j\subset H\}-1$.

Comment: I'm not seeing why such a $k$, besides $k=n$, is guaranteed to exist. How does the definition of lower central series allow such a $k$?

Comment: @AlJebr  I didn't actually use anything except that you have a finite set of nested sets starting at $e$ and going up to $G$.  At some point the transition must occur (it seems to me).